# Launch Periscope from App

Tags: ios, objective-c, launching-application

How can you launch Periscope from your applications via IBAction. I'd like to go directly to a user's periscope profile.

I tried the following:

```
NSString *periscopeURL = @"periscope://";

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:periscopeURL]];
```

I used similar code to open twitter ...and it worked.. not sure why it's not working for periscope.

any pointers are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL for periscope application is `"pscp://"`. I just found it from a tweet. https://twitter.com/viticci/status/581105793916891136

Comment: cool this launches periscope ...now I just have to figure it how to go to a specific user. Good stuff man thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Albert is correct. Our scheme is pscp://

To link directly to a broadcast id, the format is:

```
pscp://broadcast/<broadcast id>
```

For a user:

```
pscp://user/<user id>
```

However, we do not have a public lookup for a user's id (yet). Sorry...

Comment: hello....I'm trying to make a app background like periscope i.e. live background...it works but it stuck on call interruption..I did try to restart session but not works....So can you please share me how to continue session regardless interruption...thanks ....

Comment: Hey Aaron, Don't suppose you have a way to take a user to the search box with #something?